# Select any(array) in any(array)

Tags: sql, postgresql-9.1

I have a bigint[] colunm:

```
person
------
id | name  | other_information
------------------------------
 1 | Zé    | {1,2,3}
 2 | João  | {1,3}
 3 | Maria | {3,5}
```

I need select persons with 2 or 5 in other_information. How?

Comment: Can you normalize your schema so you won't have this issue?

Comment: Read up on [database normalization](http://phlonx.com/resources/nf3/).

Comment: @Falci: That would involve adding two more tables in your database. One for other_information to be held in a single table. For example, if all the different other_information you can have is numbers from 1 to 5, you would have 5 instances of that table and you would need to add an 'id' field to identify each instance. Then, you would need another table that could be called person_other_info which would contain foreign keys (FK) to both person.id and other_information.id thus making the match. You could then use a simple join and add a WHERE clause on the type contained in person_other_info.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur thanks. I know what is normalize, this was a problem with my english.

I can't change database structure :/

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from person
where 2 = ANY(other_information)
 or 5 = ANY(other_information)
```

However, using arrays is not recommended, as it results in a denormalized schema.

From the [PostgreSQL docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/arrays.html):

> Tip: Arrays are not sets; searching for specific array elements can be
>   a sign of database misdesign. Consider using a separate table with a
>   row for each item that would be an array element. This will be easier
>   to search, and is likely to scale better for a large number of
>   elements.